# GKEを使っていてkubectl get allで表示される「service/kubernetes」は何か？

Tags: docker, google-cloud, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

`kubectl get all` もしくは `kubectl get svc` をしたときにTYPEがClusterIPの「service/kubernetes」の表示が確認できます。自分でこのサービスを起動した自覚がないのですがこのサービスはデフォルトで起動されるサービスなのでしょうか？
また、少しぐぐってみたのですがこの現象についての記事が発見できませんでした。
参考になるページがあればそのURLを教えて下さい。

Comment: こちらどなたかわかりませんでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

これはデフォルトのAPIエンドポイントです。Kubernetesの中の各コンポーネント(kube-system namespace内のシステムなと)がKubernetesのAPI Serverを経由してさまざまなことをするために使うもので、必須のものなので消しても復活するはずです。